# Read Multiple Values from Array in Foreach Loop PHP

Tags: php

I want to get array values one by one and add into foreach dynamically

```
$tracker = array('1','2','3')
```

I am able to do it manually by creating multiple foreach below

```
<?php
$tracker = array( '1' );
$hashx = array( $hash );
$info = $scraper->scrape( $hashx, $tracker );
foreach ($info as $key => $value) {
    $openseed = $value['seeders'];
}

$tracker = array( '2' );
$hashx = array( $hash );
$info = $scraper->scrape( $hashx, $tracker );
foreach ($info as $key => $value) {
    $pirateseed = $value['seeders'];
}

$tracker = array( '3' );
$hashx = array( $hash );
$info = $scraper->scrape( $hashx, $tracker );
foreach ($info as $key => $value) {
    $rarbgseed = $value['seeders']; 
}
?>
```

But I want to add all array values to foreach dynamically at once instead of creating one by one manually

```
<?php
$tracker = array('1','2','3');

$hashx = array( $hash );
$info = $scraper->scrape( $hashx, $tracker );
foreach ($info as $key => $value) {
    $openseed = $value['seeders'];
}
?>
```

The above code read only first array value and i want to read all array values and store the results separately and then calculate the total number of generated result by using `array_sum()` like this below

```
$totalseed = array($pirateseed,$openseed,$rarbgseed);
echo 'Total <font color="green">Seeders:</font> '. array_sum($totalseed). '<br />';
```

Any help will be appreciated thanks

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking.

Comment: I want this `$tracker = array('udp://tracker.torrent.eu.org:451/announce', 'http://tracker.tfile.co:80/announce', 'http://retracker.spb.ru:80/announce', 'udp://open.demonii.si:1337/announce', 'http://peersteers.org:80/announce')` to get all values automatically in foreach so the foreach will get the number of seed and leech from all trackers, hope its clear now

Comment: Are you asking how to make an HTTP request for each URL?

Comment: no @Greg i know how to make request which is already shown in my codes, my question is how to generate foreach with array values automatically so it can read the seed and leech from all trackers

Comment: Still unclear. I honestly have no clue what you are asking and your code gives very little clues.

Comment: @Andreas I have updated my codes

Comment: I want a function which will get array values one by one automatically and send to foreach loops like i have created in above codes I hope its clear now

Comment: With your new update i think I understand it. Does this make sense? https://3v4l.org/tSjSk I loop the tracker array, you seem to have the same code on all three values. 3v4l obviously generates errors since there is no values or functions there. See it as a code dump.

Comment: ok thanks @Andreas and how to get results from `$openseed[]` i mean i want to echo the total results generated from array values

Comment: I don't really know what your code does so it's hard to answer. But you write that you want an array sum so I guess `echo array_sum($openseed);` is what you are looking for

Comment: ok its showing values like 6 8 9 instead of 23 I mean the result would be like 6+8+9 = 23 that means the `array_sum()` is not working properly or we missing something

Comment: How can it echo that. Are you placing the echo inside the foreach? Move it outside and below. In the loop it will only print one at the time, and the sum of 1 is 1. But if you build the array then sum it you will get one value of the.. well sum.

Comment: when i place out side of both foreach loops it shows only last value please check this https://3v4l.org/HnlMr

Comment: Try this: replace the echo array_sum with `var_dump($openseed);` this should give you an output of what the array looks like. Please copy paste it to your question.

Comment: ok it does not show the values we have to do something with `$openseed[]` array within the foreach loop first to get the exact result then `echo array_sum()` out side of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var tracker = [1,2,3];
var tracker_counts = [];

for( let i in tracker ) {
  // scrape
  tracker_counts[i] = parseInt(Math.random() * 10); // put your $value['seeders'] here
}

console.log( "Tracker seeders individually: " + tracker_counts.join(',') );
console.log( "Seeders in total: " + tracker_counts.reduce((c,v) => c+=v ) ); // use array_sum in php
```

**As PHP**

```
<?php
$tracker = [1,2,3];
$tracker_counts = [];

foreach( $tracker as $k => $v ) {
  // scrape of $v
  $tracker_counts[$k] = rand(1,9); // put your $value['seeders'] here
}

echo "Tracker seeders individually: " . implode( ', ', $tracker_counts);
echo "\n";
echo "Seeders in total: " . array_sum( $tracker_counts );
```

**Output**

```
Tracker seeders individually: 7, 9, 6
Seeders in total: 22
```

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out by the help of Andreas and Pilan so I am posting the final working solution in case of anybody else looking for it

```
<?php
$ftracker = array('udp://tracker.torrent.eu.org:451/announce', 'http://tracker.tfile.co:80/announce', 'http://retracker.spb.ru:80/announce', 'udp://open.demonii.si:1337/announce');
$hashx = array( $hash );
$info = $scraper->scrape( $hashx, $ftracker );

$openseed = [];
foreach($ftracker as $track){
    $hashx = array( $hash );
    $info = $scraper->scrape( $hashx, $track );
    foreach ($info as $key => $value) {
        $openseed[] = $value['seeders'];
    }
}
echo 'Seed for Each Tracker Separately'.implode( ', ', $openseed);
echo 'Total Seed for All Trackers'. array_sum( $openseed );
?>
```

Thanks to Andreas and Pilan

Comment: I really want to see the array, something is very wrong. If you implode an array it returns a string, a string should not be accepted in array_sum. I believe, even if the code works now it may break with a different input.